# Dynamic Choice Parameter not populated: Jenkins job + Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a dynamic choice parameter that will be populated by the resulting values of a groovy script.

The following code works and lists the contents of a dir:

```
new File("/tmp/testing/source/").eachFile() { file->  
  println file.getName()  
}
```

I created a new jenkins project, and entered the menu 'Configure' where I selected **This project is parameterized**

When I save and try to **build with parameters** nothing has been parsed from the groovy script

Comment: I think File listing is an illegal operation in Jenkins scripts, as that's a security violation (how does it know you should have access to the file system on the slave?)

Comment: That is a good point. Actually the use case of this groovy code wasn't intended to list files in a directory. But it was a quick situation I came up with to demonstrate the use of active parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with the following code:

```
list = []
def process = "ls /tmp/testing/source".execute()
process.text.eachLine {list.add it}
return list
```